# Why does my Sequelize / Typescript function error with "Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated."?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using `sequelize-typescript`, and my code is:

```
import Promise from "bluebird";
import { IncomingCall } from '../models/IncomingCall';
export function incoming(requestBody: object): Promise<IncomingCall> {
  return IncomingCall.create({
    CallSid: requestBody.CallSid
  });
}
```

But the error I get is:

```
[ts]
Type 'Bluebird<import("/src/models/IncomingCall").IncomingCall>' is not assignable to type 'Bluebird<import("/src/models/IncomingCall").IncomingCall>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
```

My `IncomingCall` is:

```
import { Model, Column, Table, DataType } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table
export class IncomingCall extends Model<IncomingCall> {

  @Column
  CallSid: string;

  @Column
  AccountSid: string;

  @Column(DataType.JSON)
  rawData: string;

}
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix was to change to:

```
export function incoming(requestBody: object): Promise<any> {
```

Answer (score 0):

`export class IncomingCall extends Model<IncomingCall>` seems incorrect as you assign to a type parameter a type that does not exist at definition time. I guess something like `export class IncomingCall extends Model<{ Callsid: string; AccountsId: string; rawData: string; }>` is better, or you could define the shape of your model in another interface altogether.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but apparently, that's how to define models with this package: https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-definition

Comment: so you have more than one definition of promise in your project? the one in bluebird and the one in lib.es5

Comment: lib.es5.core. you can check with the traceResolution flag in the compiler options